# $stateParams is undefined in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my project am using UI-router. Please check my below code to fix it

**index.js**

```
.state('survey.surveyList', {
        url: '/:id',
        templateUrl: 'survey/surveyList.html',
        controller: 'surveyController'
    });
```

**surveyController.js**

```
angular.module("adminsuite").controller("surveyController",['getAllSurveyService','$http','AuthenticationService', '$scope','$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function(getAllSurveyService,$http, AuthenticationService,$scope,$rootScope,$state,$stateParams){
       $scope.getProjSurveys = function(projId){
        var i;
        for(i in $scope.allProjects){
         if(projId == $scope.allProjects[i].ProjectID){
          $scope.allSurveys = $scope.allProjects[i].Surveys;
         }
       }
         angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".surveymodule")).removeClass('toggled');
      console.log($state.params.id);
  };
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<li ng-repeat="obj in allProjects track by  $id(obj)">
                <a ui-sref="survey.surveyList({id: obj.ProjectID})" ng-click="getProjSurveys(obj.ProjectID)" data-id="{{obj.ProjectID}}">{{obj.ProjectName}}<span class="projectsetting"><img src="./images/settings.png"/></span></a>
            </li>
```

Above are my codes. when i try to access the id value using $stateParams it shows as undefined. Using this i am trying to call another function by passing $stateParams.id as parameter but it is not working. Please help

Comment: Did you add UI router ??

Comment: yes it is working fine. onclick i can go to this state but am unable to fetch this id value...

Comment: What's the output of `$stateParams`? I would assume you didn't set anything on the `id`, can you check the URL also

Comment: also add the code the code where your are passing this id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're passing id like following :-

```
$state.go('survey.surveyList', {id : id});
```

You can get the same id using

```
$state.params.id
```

Please tell me if you have anything different than this?

**EDIT**
Prefer passing this way

```
<li ng-repeat="obj in allProjects track by  $id(obj)">
    <a ng-click="getProjSurveys(obj.ProjectID)" data-id="{{obj.ProjectID}}">{{obj.ProjectName}}<span class="projectsetting"><img src="./images/settings.png"/></span></a>
</li>

function getProjSurveys(ProjectID){
    $state.go('survey.surveyList', {id : ProjectID});
}
```

Comment: Thanks i got the param id.

Comment: In my above code i am calling getProjSurveys() on click of the projects which am getting from ng-repeat. I am facing problem like on refresh of the page it is loading the default page with id instead  i want to load  the same page the user clicked from the project list. How to do that using this params ?

Comment: yes that;s right it'll load the new page with id because you're on a new state now. If you want to do it on same page then don't use new state instead do this id stuff in popup modal..